# Azure Open AI Service

Tags: azure, service, artificial-intelligence, azure-ai

I create a private chat gpt using the git link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo . But, can see that Azure Open AI service is not available for everyone. So, whether it is still in preview? If yes after how many month this service will be available as a public service?

I tried the demo and it worked for me and want to use it in the production environment.So, want to calculate the cost of this demo as well

Answer (score 0):

> So, whether it is still in preview?

Badly formulated also - DOES IT MATTER? IT is only available upon request, for whatever reason does not really matter.

> If yes after how many month this service will be available as a public
> service?

But it IS available as a public service. You just need to get approved.

> I tried the demo and it worked for me and want to use it in the production
> environment.

And you are unaware like heck that:

- The same API is available from OpenAI.
- Even they have a waiting list still because capacity is limited, though they are SLOWLY removing that.

Use OpenAi for now with 3.5, put in an application at MS and things will be sort of solved or not. Expect things to change fast - 6 months max.

Comment: Dear @TomTom,  you are correct I am very unaware about this and very new as well. But too much intrigued with the technology. But, I have one more question here  whether using this with the help of Azure Cloud is safer or via openAI? As we will feed sensitive data of organisation and planning to use it as an interactive sharepoint.

Comment: Ah, NO Idea - OpenAi s actually using Azure, but otherwise Azure has decent contracts, not sure what OpenAi would offer you. TIme to buttle up into "I am a professional" shoes and CONTACT THE VENDOR.